# Visibility of Welcome Back Container and Bottom Navigation Bar on screen all time while scrolling

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am writing a code in flutter for my application and my page looks like this:
[Screen View from Starting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gG4M.png)
[Screen View from Ending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGL7w.png)
What I want is that my Widget where I have written welcome back etc and an avatar shown with it should remain all-time visible even when I am scrolling. Also, i want my Bottom Navigation bar to remain visible as well.

My code for Welcome Screen:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xffe8e5af),
      elevation: 0,
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.menu,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) {
                return BluetoothConnectBand();
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 22, horizontal: 47),
                width: size.width,
                height: 157.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(40.0),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(40.0),
                  ),
                  color: const Color(0xffe8e5af),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Welcome Back\nNabia',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                        fontSize: 21,
                        color: const Color(0xff000000),
                        height: 1.380952380952381,
                      ),
                      textHeightBehavior:
                          TextHeightBehavior(applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 23.0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Check your daily history',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                          fontSize: 13,
                          color: const Color(0xff6c6c6c),
                          height: 1.5384615384615385,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                      textHeightBehavior:
                          TextHeightBehavior(applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                width: size.width,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 33),
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 48,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/avatar.jpg'),
                    radius: 42,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

and for Bottom Navigation Bar is:

```
Container(
  height: 70,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topRight: Radius.circular(20), topLeft: Radius.circular(20)),
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey, spreadRadius: 0, blurRadius: 5),
    ],
  ),
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
      topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
    ),
    child: BottomNavigationBar(
      //elevation: 7,
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      //fixedColor: const Color(0xff898a8f),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      unselectedFontSize: 10,
      selectedFontSize: 10,
      selectedLabelStyle: optionStyle,
      currentIndex: _currentIndex,
      selectedItemColor: const Color(0xffd4d411),
      unselectedItemColor: const Color(0xffd4d411),
      onTap: onTabTapped, // this will be set when a new tab is tapped
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.home),
          title: new Text(
            'Home',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
              fontSize: 10,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.mail),
          title: new Text(
            'Caregiver',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
              fontSize: 10,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person_pin_circle),
          title: Text(
            'History',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
              fontSize: 10,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person),
          title: Text(
            'Profile',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
              fontSize: 10,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Please help me out with what I should write to make my screen work perfectly because I am a beginner to Flutter and I am still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use an `Expanded` widget to let the scrollable area take up the remaining space. You would have to move the welcome-widget outside of the `SingleChildScrollView`.

Here's a simplified example that might help you.

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  body: Column(
    children: [
      _Welcome(),
      Expanded(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: _Charts(),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
        label: "1",
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
        label: "2",
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

When the `BottomNavigationBar` is passed into the `Scaffold`'s `bottomNavigationBar` parameter, it should always be visible and remain on the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Thank you!
it worked perfectly just the way I wanted.

Comment: Glad to hear that :) If that's the case, don't forget to mark this answer as the correct one and an upvote is always welcome as well